# ADT20 NDK Debug Fails

Tags: android, debugging, gdb, adt, android-ndk

I have been developing some native code under android's ndk, and had the need for debugging, ofcourse.

I used the preview 3 of the ADT20 & the corresponding tools 
but then the official update got out so I downloaded a clean version of Eclipse, SDK, ADT and NDK (crystax build, which I also used with the preview and worked fine)
but now I can't connect the debugger. What I see in the console is the following :

```
warning: .dynamic section for "/home/user/Development/Projects/MyDevProject/Android/ProjectName/obj/local/armeabi/libcrypto.so" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 63 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
[New Thread 1614]
[New Thread 1617]
[New Thread 1618]
[New Thread 1619]
[New Thread 1620]
[New Thread 1621]
[New Thread 1622]
[New Thread 1623]
[New Thread 1624]
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

I confirm that I have NDK_DEBUG=1 defined and all the stuff setup, since I used this config last week and worked like a charm.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting the same exact thing, except for the "No symbol table..." messages at the end. Which OS are you on?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.04, Java 6, Eclipse 3.6, Crystax extended NDK (but google's NDK doesn't work either)

Comment: Confirmed on Ubuntu 12.04, OS X 10.7 and Windows 7. All show the same behavior. Android NDK.

Comment: I had the same error. Take a look at my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705109/how-to-debug-c-c-code-ndk-in-eclipse