# Debugging Android NDK C/C++ code in Eclipse - breakpoints are not hit

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I downloaded Android SDK Bundle for Linux and Android NDK. ADT was installed, I installed CDT.

I created a Android project and added native support (jni). Then I wrote native function in java-code which exporting in c++ code. In c++ code I defined this function.

Java-code:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
}

private native String get_text_from_cpp();
```

c++ code (h):

```
extern "C"{
   JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_test_MainActivity_get_1text_1from_1cpp(JNIEnv *, jobject);
}
```

c++ code (cpp):

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_test_MainActivity_get_1text_1from_1cpp(JNIEnv * env, jobject){
    return env->NewStringUTF( "hello from C++" );
}
```

Code works without errors. But when I set breakpoint in c++ code it is not hit.

build-nkd NDK_DEBUG = 1 - are included

I followed this instructions http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin

Android.mk in jni/ has LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g

I have read very much information but I could't customized Eclipse. Please, help anybody.

PS: I am sorry for my English is not my native language. I have difficulty in writing.

Add: Also during debug in console shows:
"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 95 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will retry eventurally.  Meanwhile, it is likely
that GDB is unable to debug shared library initializers
or resolve pending breakpoints after dlopen()."

Comment: Maybe, you ran Debug, which launches the Java debugger? You should right click the project and choose "debug as"->"android native application"

Comment: Yes, I chose "debug as"->"android native application". In "Debug Configurates" was added new configuration (in "Android Native Application") http://gyazo.com/567ae4fa0e8aa2363676789b7df780be

Comment: Maybe, your app executes the JNI function very early, so that  the debugger is not ready yet? From the code you posted, it is not clear where the native method is called. I'd suggest some button in your Activity which will launch the native method. Then, you have a chance to try several times.

Comment: BTW, the warning about 95 libraries is perfectly normal. These are the system libraries which you don't want to debug, and don't have sources for.

Comment: The native method is called in onCreate() method. Which are buttons?

Comment: *The native method is called in onCreate()* - that's what I feared. Add a button to your activity, and call the same native method onClick of that button - it will be easier to catch the breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much! Debugger works excellent. I have interest why is debugger not ready in onCreate method?

Answer (score 12):

The trick I use is to put a usleep call as the very first native line in my debug code.

This makes your thread sleep and gives the debugger a chance to be ready for you.

```
#include <unistd.h>

.
.
.

#ifndef NDEBUG
usleep(5000 * 1000);
#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

After struggling a *lot* to debug on **Eclipse** this is my recipe:

Do the usual steps:

- Add `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` before loading your native library. This might help.
- Add `APP_OPTIM := debug` in `Application.mk`
- Build with `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1`

Then, what I found different:

- Open a console and run:

`adb pull /system/bin/linker <your_project_base_dir>/obj/local/armeabi/linker`

Depending on your device you might have to write `armeabi` or `armeabi-v7a`. You only need to do it once (I noticed that running `ndk-gdb` manually was doing that. Executing that command manually the breakpoints started to work)

- Finally, to debug use the menu "Run -> Debug As -> Android Native Application"

Comment: Pulls some other libs too (at least in 4.9 toolchain)

Comment: What's the /system/bin/linker ? where do I find this link. I'm a windows user.

Answer (score 5):

You can use DS-5 CE Android Debug tool provided by ARM as a plugin to your eclipse. It works really well and provides a very good and easy UI for debugging. From my personal experience it is lots better than the traditional way of debugging the ndk app.

Please refer the below link which will provide you with the details of how to use the DS-5 debugger:

https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/tutorials/android-native-app-debug-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for link. I tried to use DS-5 but when I create a new debug configuration I cannot select a device to connect to from the Connections drop down box, there's nothing there.

Answer (score 3):

Your app executes the JNI function very early, so that the debugger is not ready yet. Unfortunately,  it takes a while for gdb to establish the remote connection, see 
http://visualgdb.com/documentation/appstartup

Instead of fighting the windmills, add a button to your activity, and call the same native method onClick() of that button - it will be easier to catch the breakpoint.

BTW, the warning about 95 libraries is perfectly normal. These are the system libraries which you don't want to debug, and don't have sources for.

Answer (score 1):

consider adding:

`android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`

before your native call, this makes your app wait until the debugger attaches, could help you avoid sleeping / using a button.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and the only thing that worked for me was putting

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

before the JNI library is loaded. This gave enough time for the debugger to attach before the call to `System.loadLibrary` crashed the app. Helped me to locate the problem C++ code.