# How to set C++ breakpoint in Eclipse Android Native Development Kit (NDK)?

Tags: android, c++, android-emulator, android-ndk, breakpoints

I'm trying to port a Linux C++ application to Android using the Android Native Development Kit (NDK).  Thus far, I have my ported application running on an emulator on my Mac.  I tried setting a break point in Eclipse in my C++ code at a particular line, but the code runs through my breakpoint without stopping.  The java breakpoints on a line work fine, it is just the C++ breakpoints that seem to have no effect and the code just runs as written and returns.

How can I set a breakpoint in my C++ code so that I can step through the native code in my Android application under development in an emulator?

Comment: Somewhat related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705109/debugging-android-ndk-c-c-code-in-eclipse-breakpoints-are-not-hit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set a C++ breakpoint while debugging Java. You need to run `Debug As > Android Native Application`. In Eclipse, a hittable breakpoint has a tick.

In order to debug as Android native application, your application needs to have `Native Support`, you need to have the `CDT plugin` and you shoud add `NDK_DEBUG=1` in the build command.

More info [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin).

Answer (score 1):

I do not agree with Pau Guillamon's answer that states:

> You can't set a C++ breakpoint while debugging Java.

You can set a C++ breakpoint while debugging Java. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, where you can do this:

```
root#apt-get install gcj-sdk
............................
root#man gcj
```

To learn more, see:

- *Compiling Java with GCJ* by Per Bothner
- *Java Debugging with gdb* by Matt Welsh