# Debugging cocos2dx in eclipse Android NDK

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm starting to use cocos2dx in my personal computer with Windows 7. It was a pain in the ass configuring all the environment with Eclipse and its CDT plugin, and Android NDK, but finally, I could run a game inside my Android phone.

The problem I'm facing right now is that I can't debug my game. I tried many things but looks like it is not able to reach the breakpoints I put.

Here is what I'm using in my Properties>C++ Build:

```
C:\ndk-r9c\ndk-build.cmd NDK_DEBUG=1 DEBUG=1 NDK_APPLICATION_MK=jni/Application.mk
```

And this is what I've got in Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -DDEBUG -    DANDROID_DEBUG_LEVEL=ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE -DJSON_DEBUG
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

I don't know what else to try. I tried creating a new C++ debug configuration, but it needs a C++ executable and I can't find it inside the obj or bin folder of my Android project.

Any tips please? :(

Cheers!

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705109/how-to-debug-c-c-code-ndk-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

from eclipse you can do a right click on your project, and select `Debug as` -> `Android Native Application` to debug it.

I've made a [screencast here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjsC-lKUgM8) demonstrating this feature.