# Debugging Opencv Android app

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, opencv, android-ndk

I am working on OpenCV for Android. I would want to debug the C++ code in the eclipse. For this, I found few StackOVerflow answers. But still I am not successful in Debugs as a Native App.

Steps I followed:

1. Added android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger(); before loading your native library. This might help.
2. Added APP_OPTIM := debug in Application.mk
3. Run ndk-build NDK_BUILD=1

After building the app, "Run -> Debug As -> Android Native Application"

Error which I get in Android Console:
Unknown Application ABI: 
Unable to detect application ABI's

Ref:
[Debugging Android NDK C/C++ code in Eclipse - breakpoints are not hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705109/how-to-debug-c-c-code-ndk-in-eclipse)

Comment: What is your log? Android log give a lot of info in different lines, so please paste it to give us more information.

Answer (score 0):

What API Level are you compiling against ? When debugging, you can encounter this kind of errors when compiling against an old platform version.

You can try setting `APP_PLATFORM:=android-14` inside *Application.mk* and set *minSdkVersion*  to at least 14 inside your manifest. Once this is done, you may clean your project and try debugging again.