# Debug jni Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a few break point in my c++ code that are not getting executed. I have done the following steps with no luck:

1) AndroidManifest.xml added `<application android:debuggable="true>`

2) Ran `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1` to generate the gdb.setup and gdbserver

3) Added  `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` before loading your native library. This might help.

4)Add `APP_OPTIM := debug` in Application.mk

5) Ran `adb pull /system/bin/linker <your_project_base_dir>/obj/local/armeabi/linker`

6) In run configurations added the Android Native and ran that project.

However nothing is really happening. Any suggestions or steps that I'm missing? Or any resources on the matter ?

Comment: are you using extern C block for running cpp code..?

Comment: yes I am in the header file

Comment: The code is producing the right output but I would like to step through my code since it will get more complicated

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17961227/942224  it may help you.

Comment: thx. added some extra steps but still no luck